# What did Bruce intend for Blake after The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

The ending of *The Dark Knight Rises* implies that Bruce Wayne bequeaths the Batcave (and apparently, by extension, the identity of Batman) to Blake. We even get to see Blake inside the Batcave, looking at rad Batman equipment rising out of the water.

But does it make sense for Blake to become the new Batman? Blake might have the right attitude, but putting on the Batsuit doesn't make him Batman. He arguably lacks many of the things that made Bruce Wayne a terrifying Batman, e.g.,

- Several years of painfully intensive training in martial arts, including knowledge of "theatricality and deception".
- A massive fortune to maintain all the hi-tech equipment.
- The loyalty of Lucius Fox, who is ultimately the person responsible for procuring and developing all the hi-tech equipment.

So, did Bruce Wayne *really* want Blake to be the new Batman?

Comment: He could always just go up stairs and ask Bruce if anything happens...

Comment: I'm sure that the fact that Bruce told Robin where to find the bat-cave is sufficient to convince Fox. Alfred is left with the Wayne fortune and can presumably bankroll the new Batman, Wayne Manor is secure and Fox has been rebuilding Bruce's toys in anticipation that they'll be needed again "*Fox had spent months repairing the damage from Bane’s invasion—and beefing up the security—but the underground armory looked as good as new, as did the new and remaining prototypes. Lucius intended to keep a close watch on his inventory, just in case they were ever needed again.*" - Novelisation.

Comment: I'm sure we'll find out in the next Nolan-Batman movie.

Comment: Nevertheless, Since **he is Robin** so I suppose he would create his own persona using tools and base given to him by Batman. I don't believe he would put on the Bat suit because then he'd be just like another copycat Batman like we saw in 2nd nolan movie

Comment: Blake becoming Batman would be consistent with Bruce's idea of Batman being "more than a man" and a symbol.  For Batman to reappear after being thought dead, having the same appearance and using the same eqiupment, would fuel ideas of Batman as an almost mythical being.  He wouldn't be just another copycat, because he was hand-picked by Bruce, and like Bruce, was committed to not using lethal force.

Comment: @Koldito : Just wondering if you are looking for anything further in the answer below?  :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Blake actually had most of the things you mention

Blake did not have years of martial arts training, but he was a trained law enforcement officer.  He may not have known Lucius Fox for years, but they were collaborating in Gotham during Bane's lockdown of the city and would have gained each other's respect.

While Bruce had no money to leave Blake, Lucius has money and resources as one of the few remaining board members of Wayne Enterprises, not to mention the expertise to help Blake maintain the contents of the cave.

More generally, Bruce and Blake develop a spiritual bond in the film through the fact they were both orphans.  It is highly implied in the film that Blake became a police officer as a result of his childhood and that he is restless for a cause, much like Bruce had been.

Bruce may not necessarily have intended for Blake to become the Batman but trusts that he will use the resources left to him to be whatever Gotham needs — this could very well be *Robin*, given Blake's actual first name.

Comment: “this could very well be Robin, given Blake's actual first name” — Or maybe Blake has a habit of eating chicken wings after dark, and one evening Alfred says “Oh Master Blake, all these chicken wings at night, I shall have to start calling you Night Wing”, and Blake goes “Hold on a minute!”